# python, loading a string from file

Tags: string, numpy, sys

I'm trying to load a .txt file into my python project using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

g = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1])
```

this command has worked for me when .txt file was a 0/1 matrix, but not
working now as it is a string matrix (4*7 table of words like "crew")
error says "cant convert string to float".. any help?

Comment: Have you read the docs for `loadtxt`?  It's default mode is to read numbers.  There are lots of parameters to control how it loads a file.  Or try `np.genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `dtype` parameter. ([here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html))

> dtype : data-type, optional
>   Data-type of the resulting array; default: float. If this is a structured data-type, the resulting array will be 1-dimensional, and each row will be interpreted as an element of the array. In this case, the number of columns used must match the number of fields in the data-type.

The default is float, which results in the error you are  pointing out in your question.

Comment: another question:
I want to map a dictionary with 2 values
d = { "y", [7][8] ;  "f", [90][7] } and so on..
I've tried to use set default, doesn't work for me.. I don't know how to initialize this, because I tried d[key][0] = 4 and it doesn't work..

Anyone?

Comment: Don't ask 'another question' in a comment.

Comment: As @hpaulj mentioned it might be more appropriate to create a new question for this (make sure to formulate it well and perhaps add a reference to this question). I however hope that you already managed to solve your issue! ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option is using pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.read_table(filename, sep=" ", header=None).values
```

(Assuming the separator is a whitespace and there is no header column. Specify otherwise).

Comment: "list indices must be integer, not float"
does anyone know what this means??
just trying
" for key in m :x=m[key] "